# List implementation

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Suppose there is a **list of numbers**-stored in an array, queue, linked list or whatever supports a list data structure(i.e. **sequence of numbers matters**). Now, suppose we want to add a new object after adding a number to the existing list(list.add()). But, list.add() takes in the original list and returns a new list containing the numbers from original list and the new number. The original list object is not changed in any way by the function add().

So, to implement this **one way is that** we make a copy of the original list in the function, add the new number to it and then return it. This takes O(n) time.

So is there any other way by which we can do this job in less time than O(n).

**EDIT 1:
The element is to be added at the last. The returned object by add() should contain all the numbers in the original list and the new number. The original list is left unaltered.**

**EDIT 2:
I think it might be possible if we don't copy the entire list every time we add a number to the list. Is there any possibility in this regard?**

Comment: Where are you adding the new node?  to the head, the tail, the middle?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth...to the end

Answer (score 0):

Appending to the head of a linked list will be O(1).

Alternatively, supporting random insertion is a topic of much research lately. Clojure and Scala use something similar to a [Hash array mapped trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie), except an immutable variant that allows for faster updates by copying only the branch that is affected by the update in O(logn). When the branching factor is high (i.e. 32), this also allows for effectively constant lookup.

Comment: @dicarlo2...the insertion is at the last...Can you please illustrate your answer...I want the returned object to contain all the nodes in the original list and the new number too. The original object is not returned and is not altered by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to copy?

You can just add to the end of the list or array in O(1)

Basically just add the number behind and use the same parameters and increment size by 1 and then create a list object and that's O(1)

Comment: This has to do with certain programming styles and concerns, usually making objects immutable.  Often this is in the interests of making dealing with multi-threaded or concurrent code safer and easier.  And adding an element to the 'tail' end of a list/array isn't _necessarily_ O(1), that's going to depend on implementation (linked lists are usually O(n), for example)

Comment: Yes or a BST would be logarithmic, you are right. Does this also then involve the releasing of the previous object? How is this safer with concurrent code?

Comment: Say you have one list of items, and two threads/processes - one logging all items, and the other putting the items in order.  If care isn't taken, items may be logged more than once, or not at all.  Synchonizing access won't work, because it would end up removing the threaded implementation benefits.  So, the logger should work on a copy of the list (order is assumed unimportant).  Certain languages/platforms may have special implementations that make the copy more efficient than an O(n) operation (iterating to copy), which is what the logging requires.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what other kind of functionality you need to support, but if `add` is the only method you are concerned about, you can make a wrapper class that basically maintains a new list that represents the portion you are adding onto the original list. Then, a `lookup` into this wrapper class takes into consideration the concatenation of the original and the new list.

Here is some example pseudo-C# code:

```cs
public class ListWrapper
{
    private ArrayList<T> Original;
    private ArrayList<T> ConcatenatedPortion;

    public ImmutableList(ArrayList<T> original)
    {
        Original = original;
        ConcatenatedPortion = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public bool Add(<T> element)
    {
        return ConcatenpatedPortion.Add(element);
    }

    public <T> Get(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if (index < Original.Length)
            return Original.Get(index);

        int newIndex = index - Original.Length;

        if (newIndex < ConcatenatedPortion.Length)
            return ConcatenatedPortion.Get(newIndex);

        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```